# How to get Login customer entity_id in the template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to get Login customer `entity_id` in the template in **Magento 2**
 print on `list.phtml`

Comment: Please specify your Magento version correctly.

Comment: Magento CLI version 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can do a customer **collection** to get all customers data, then you can add filters and you get what you want.

```
//Load customer data
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection();
foreach($customerObj as $customerObjdata )
{
    \Zend_Debug::dump($customerObjdata ->getData());
}
```

### Update

To get just the customer loggedin data

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerObj->isLoggedIn()) {
    \Zend_Debug::dump($customerObj->getCustomer()->getData());
    \Zend_Debug::dump($customerObj->getCustomer()->getEntityId());
}
```

Comment: want to only login customer data not all customer data

Comment: @Nitesh kumar Singh look my update

Comment: You're welcome, good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code to get **`customer_id`** in **PHTML**.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); // prints customer's entity_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what your looking for

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()."<br/>";  // Get Customer Id
    echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()."<br/>";  // Get  Full Name
    echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail()."<br/>"; // Get Email Name
    echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId()."<br/>";  // Get Customer Group Id
  }
```

Comment: on template     echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()."<br/>";  // Get Customer Id
getting  Null not coustom id

Comment: var_dump($customerSession->getCustomer()->getData()); print on template gettting only array(1) { ["group_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: so that means its a guest session